# Why linux mint doesn't shutdown the notebook HP 15?

Tags: linux-mint

I had Ubuntu 16.04, which neither turn off nor restart. I formatted the hard disk then I installed Linux mint "Serena", I had hope that this time would be working, but the initial problem in shutdown remains. I installed the corresponding updates for the operating system, and nothing happens. Before I tried too with settings on grub file, what more to do?

My previous post in Ask Ubuntu:

> I had an ubuntu 16.04.2 installed in a notebook hp. The problem
>   started when I noticed ubuntu was enabled to shutdown correctly. I
>   means, show the screen of poweroff but freeze. And finally I pressed
>   the button ON/off to force the shutdown. I bear this problem throught
>   this time, but this week I had the chance and time to format my
>   notebook and reinstall ubuntu. I downloaded ubuntu 17 and installed
>   it. Started other trouble with ubuntu 17, It stands frozen suddenly, I
>   can't do anything, neither open terminal. Then I do a format again, I
>   reinstalled the old ubuntu 16.04.02 from a booteable pendrive.
>
> I began the test, the problem of shutting and restarting is keeping!
>   Now I don't know what more to do.
>
> **The features:**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0e)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0e)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx, Celeron N2000 Series USB xHCI (rev 0e)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 0e)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 0e)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 0e)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 0e)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series USB EHCI (rev 0e)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SMBus Controller (rev 0e)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

Answer (score 1):

Linux Mint 18.1 "Serena" is based on Ubuntu 16.04, so it's normal if it still doesn't work.

Looks like a regular driver problem though. Full support for Intel Atom-based laptops on Linux is not easy, so that'll generally takes time.

However, before trying anything else. Did you updated your Ubuntu to 16.04.3 ?

If you did, just install Ukuu by following this: [tutorial](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/02/ukuu-install-latest-kernels-ubuntu-linux-mint/), to install the latest LTS Kernel -and drivers-, which is 4.14 and see if things gets better.

Also, for stability reasons, please never ever install any Ubuntu releases outside LTS.